# просмотр реестра

Tags: delphi, windows, delphi-7, реестр

Начинаю изучать работу с реестром. Создал, удалил а вот просмотр не получается.

```
procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Reg:TRegistry;
begin
   Reg:=TRegistry.Create;
   Reg.RootKey:=HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
   Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly('Software\RegDemo\IntKey');
   ShowMessage(Reg ... ); // как просмотреть значение ?
   Reg.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Я, конечно, не спец по дельфи, но вы только открыли ключ. Наверное, надо еще прочитать из него нужный параметр...

Comment: `reg.readInteger('....')` вам не достаточно?

Comment: там и другие методы `read...` есть, если что.

Comment: Просьба не как ответ, а как коммент полезный если что или игнор.
Немного не по теме, но полезным будет.
Буржуины (под толерантное название подходят? если нет - Угнетатели\нет - Капиталисты\нет - Мировое правительство\нет - на ваше усмотрение заменить) тут вот чего удумали :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493303/how-can-a-32-bit-program-read-the-real-64-bit-version-of-the-registry Обязательно учитывать!

Answer (score 3):

Я делаю так:

```
var
  Reg:TRegistry;
begin
  Reg:=TRegistry.Create;
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    Reg.OpenKey('Software\RegDemo\', True);

    if Reg.ValueExists('IntKey') then
      Result := Reg.ReadString('IntKey')
    else
      Result := ''

  finally
    Reg.CloseKey;
    FreeAndNil(Reg);
  end;
end;
```

Где `Reg.ReadString` изменяется в зависимости от типа данных

Comment: я, к сожалению, не могу добавить код, т.к. ремонт и все железки в коробках. но я точно помню, что возникала проблема с REG_EXPAND_SZ - и у мну есть модуль, кот. с ним работает (редко юзается). если такой тип не нужен - все решено :) или поиском если нужен. в свое время много времени на него ушло. да, ложка дегтя.

Answer (score 0):

сделал таким образом но сообщение выходит пустым((( в реестре значение в MD5.

```
var
  hK: HKey;
  Value: PAnsiChar;
  L: Longint;
begin
  RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\RegDemo\IntKey', hK);
  L:=1024;
  GetMem(Value,L);
  RegQueryValue(hK, NIL, Value, L);
  ShowMessage(Value);
  FreeMem(Value);
end;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нафига ковырять не пойми что, если у вас есть класс `TRegistry` ?

Comment: не все значения реестра можно считать "штатными" средствами Дельфей.